# Is it possible to change the background automatically when charging battery?

Tags: battery, charging, customization

This is a feature of older nokias, I would like to have it on android! On a related note, it would be nice to have a different background when silenced or on airplane mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, using [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).

See "Set Wallpaper" [action](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html) and "Power" [state](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html). It even looks like it'd be rather easy to configure that event.

For your related notes, also see "Airplane Mode" [state](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html) and %SILENT [variable](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found two live wallpaper apps for you:

- [Liquid Battery](http://www.appbrain.com/app/liquid-battery/com.kogash.android.wallpapers.LB)
- [Power Puddle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004YWUV40)

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out [Battery Fun!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.batteryfun)